# Npm install didn`t work if nodejs version 16.0.0

Tags: reactjs, npm, next.js

Hi there I just cloned my repo and tried to nnpm install and I got this error

```
npm install

npm ERR! code ERESOLVE

npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree

npm ERR!

npm ERR! Found: react@16.13.0

npm ERR! node_modules/react

npm ERR!   react@"16.13.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer react@">=16.8" from framer-motion@2.9.5
npm ERR!   node_modules/framer-motion

npm ERR!     framer-motion@"^2.7.5" from the root project

npm ERR!   23 more (react-dom, next, rc-drawer, react-custom-scrollbars, ...)

npm ERR!

npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:

npm ERR! peer react@"^16.13.1 || ^17.0.0" from @mdx-js/react@1.6.22

npm ERR! node_modules/@theme-ui/mdx/node_modules/@mdx-js/react

npm ERR!   @mdx-js/react@"^1.0.0" from @theme-ui/mdx@0.3.5

npm ERR!   node_modules/@theme-ui/mdx

npm ERR!     @theme-ui/mdx@"0.3.5" from theme-ui@0.3.5

npm ERR!     node_modules/theme-ui

npm ERR!       theme-ui@"^0.3.1" from the root project

npm ERR!     1 more (@theme-ui/theme-provider)

npm ERR!

npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry

npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps

npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

Answer (score 0):

So if I figured it out, that I had to change the version of my nodejs it doesn`t work if version 16, but it worked on version 14.